# Hibernate not adding cascade type in SQL statement

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have one class **User** and another **Role**. Inside **User** class I am storing **Role** objects as

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Now when I run my application with *show-sql* set to *true*, I see the following sql statement in my console.

```
Hibernate: alter table user_roles add constraint FKh8ciramu9cc9q3qcqiv4ue8a6 foreign key (role_id) references roles (id)
Hibernate: alter table user_roles add constraint FKhfh9dx7w3ubf1co1vdev94g3f foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
```

My question is that why am I not seeing any cascade operation in the alter table statement and how can I make it to have **CascadeType** in the DDL statemet.

I am using *Hibernate 5.4.22*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CascadeType` of JPA/Hibernate is completely unrelated to the `cascade` option of foreign key constraints.

Hibernate implements the cascade option in Hibernate itself, since the operations that need cascading don't even exist on the database level in many cases, e.g. persist and merge.

Comment: Is there any way I can make the database table to have any cascade type through hibernate? 
Or is it given that, if I declare the cascade type as above, I hibernate will take care of the cascade operations itself?

Comment: > Is there any way I can make the database table to have any cascade type through hibernate? No, but you shouldn't create your schema through Hibernate anyway, at least not in production.

Comment: > s it given that, if I declare the cascade type as above, I hibernate will take care of the cascade operations itself?

yes.